# Ksql for voting count (user can update their vote)

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have voting stream, where one user an vote feature.
User can change their vote as many as they like, but one user counted only once.
So I have this data on kafka topic `votes`.

| Key | Value | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | `{"vote" : "feat-A" }` | Alex new vote |
| Bob | `{"vote" : "feat-A" }` | Bob New Vote |
| Alex | `{"vote" : "feat-B" }` | Alex change vote |
| Bob | `{"vote" : "feat-B" }` | Bob change vote |
| Charlie | `{"vote" : "feat-C" }` | Charlie new vote |

At the end of the sample above, there must be :

- feat-A : 0
- feat-B : 2
- feat-C : 1

What is the ksql to do this?

I try

```
    CREATE STREAM featurevotes (
      user STRING,
      vote STRING
    ) WITH (
      KAFKA_TOPIC = 'votes',
      VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
    );
    
-- wrong
    SELECT vote, COUNT(user)
      FROM featurevotes
    GROUP BY vote
    EMIT CHANGES;

-- also wrong
    SELECT vote, COUNT_DISTINCT(user)
      FROM featurevotes
    GROUP BY vote
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

But it returns :

- feat-A : 2
- feat-B : 2
- feat-C : 1

Comment: If you count any users, you'll never get 0 value. Clearly that's not what you want... You should probably modify your original data to separate initial votes from changed votes if you plan on querying a difference in values. If it weren't a stream, you could get the latest vote with a max(timestamp), then count those